# display custom selection area on html page using javascript

Tags: javascript

On an html page, can I calculate an invidual character's x,y coordinates and its render size on screen ?

I am asking this question because I was wondering how google docs does it ? If you look inspect selected region in google docs, it places an overlay on the selected region. I couldn't figure out how they do it.

Google search does not return anything relevant. May be I am not searching for the right thing!

Any clues ?

Thanks,
Parth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what Google Docs does is to draw and measure each individual character off-screen. I've done this on a recent project and it's relatively easy:

1. create a span
2. give it the right styles
3. set its `innerHTML`
4. position it off-screen
5. add it to the DOM
6. check its offsetWidth
7. remove it from the DOM

For more information, see this Google blog post: https://drive.googleblog.com/2010/05/whats-different-about-new-google-docs.html

Comment: that's one elaborate hack ... !! :) Facebook docs does not seems to use that. FB docs some how uses the inbuilt browser selection and then when a formatting option is selected it does some processing to apply it. looks like i will have to play around with it a little bit to understand it better.

Comment: @user756919: It's a little elaborate, yes, but there's not really a sensible cross-browser alternative if you're drawing your own selection. Here's a Google blog post about their approach: http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2010/05/whats-different-about-new-google-docs.html. I haven't looked into FB docs, I might check that out later.

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print
    {
        body * {
                  visibility:hidden;
                }
        #printablecontent { display: block; }
    }
    </style>
```